# MATLAB nested for loop to read variables to insert in equation

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I have variables in Matlab workspace, which consists of coordinates of nonzero pixels of image.

[image: Example]

From that variable stored, i want to read row by column to define x1, x2, y1, y2 values so that i can apply to my equation.

For example on the first loop:

```
x1=127, y1=38
x2=128, y2=38
```

Second loop (which its stepsize is 1):

```
x1=128, y1=38
x2=129, y2=38
```

These are the code that i thought of but i know it won't work.

```
%r is for the row values, and c is for the column values.%
coordinates = [r, c];

%To define the size of my coordinates%
num_rows = size(coordinates,1);
num_cols = size(coordinates,2);

%To calculate the slopes using row-column values%
for x1 = 1:num_rows
    for y1 = 1:num_cols
        for x2 = 2:num_rows
            for y2 = 2:num_cols

                  %Calculate M%
                  M = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

How can i define the values x1,x2,y1,y2 by using nested for loop? so that i can use my x1,x2,y1,y2 in my equation  slopes = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1).

Comment: I am sort of lost, where/which  are those 2D arrays?

Comment: Its not clear from your question what you want to ask. Please describe and provide more information.

Comment: @Divakar sorry, i am still new in using programming terms. it's not array, it's variable that i collect and stored in my workspace. i edit the question and includes a picture. hopes it's clear enough. TQ

Comment: @articuno i already edit and include a picture. still new in using programming terms, i got it wrong. TQ

Comment: Can number of columns in the matrix `coordinates` be more than 2 ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. 
Do you simply want to calculate M for each row pair, or as your code suggest, want to calculate every single possible combination of pairs, like ([13,2]-[1,2]) / ([11,1] - [5,1]) ?

Comment: @articuno that coordinates is extracted from image. i convert non-zero image pixels to row-column coordinates, i used [row,col] = find(image);

Comment: @syakey In that case, the answer posted by me will work for you. Just take care of NaNs (if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, your `coordinates` matrix will have only 2 columns where column 1 represents `x` coordinates and column 2 represents corresponding `y` coordinates. In that case you can find the slope matrix simply by-

```
coordinates = [r, c];
num_rows = size(coordinates,1);
shiftedCoordinates = coordinates(2:num_rows,:);
diffMat = shiftedCoordinates-coordinates(1:num_rows-1,:);
slopeMat = diffMat(:,2)./diffMat(:,1);
```

`slopeMat` is the matrix which you want (`M`)

Comment: i had tried your codes and it works. it's much simpler than using the for loops which i myself lost in doing it. thank you, this solve my problem.